# Python Twitter API Stream tweepy trying to save data to a CSV file

Tags: python, api, csv, twitter

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

ckey = 'hidden due to question'
csecret = 'hidden due to question'
atoken = 'hidden due to question'
asecret = 'hidden due to question'

class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            print (data)
            saveFile = open('TwitterAPI.csv','a')
            saveFile.write(data)
            saveFile.Write('\n')
            saveFIle.close()
            return (True)
    def on_error(self, status):
        print (status)

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["car"])
```

The problem with the code above is the fact that it keeps on coming up with an error message stating that there is an unexpected unindent at the //def on_error// row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You open a `try` block without catching the exception.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Also be careful, python is case sensitive, so `saveFile` is not `saveFIle`, nor `saveFile.write()` is `saveFile.Write()`...

Editing your `on_data()` handler as follow should make it work :

```
def on_data(self, data):
    try:
        print(data)
        with open('TwitterAPI.csv','a') as f:
            f.write(data)
    except Exception as e: # here catch whatever exception you may have.
        print('[!] Error : %s' % e)
```

**Edit :** Below is your full code reworked :

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

ckey = 'hidden due to question'
csecret = 'hidden due to question'
atoken = 'hidden due to question'
asecret = 'hidden due to question'


class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            print(data)
            with open('TwitterAPI.csv','a') as f:
                f.write(data)
        except:
            pass

    def on_error(self, status):
        print (status)

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["car"])
```

Comment: an error message stating that the unexpected indent is still there

'class listener(StreamListener):

       def on_data(self, data):
           try:
            print(data)
            with open('TwitterAPI.csv','a') as f:
                f.write(data)
            except Exception as e: # here catch whatever exception you may have.
            print('[!] Error : %s' % e)
    def on_error(self, status):
        print (status)

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["car"])'

Comment: sorry i am new to python and have never used it before

Comment: in the section where you have told me to insert the new script it states that it is an invalid syntax

Comment: class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            print(data)
            with open('TwitterAPI.csv','a') as f:
                f.write(data)
            except Exception as e: # here catch whatever exception you may have.
                print('[!] Error : %s' % e)
    def on_error(self, status):
        print (status)

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["car"])

the error only appears once it has been run

Comment: this is not the error message this is your source code.
I need the error message, not the code